# Find the matrix in the canonical base

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the endomorphism $$f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3, (x,y,z) \mapsto (7x+2y+2z,-4x+y-2z,2x+y+4z).$$ 
It asks to write the matrix of $f$ in the canonical base.

Is this the correct result ?
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    7 & -4 & 2 \\
    2 & 1 & 1 \\
    2 & -2 & 4 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: You can check this by applying the matrix to the vector $(x,y,z)^T$.

Answer (score -1):

You should put the images under $f$ of the vectors in the canonical basis in the **columns** of your matrix instead of as rows.

Therefore, the correct matrix would be the transpose of the one you got.

Comment: Unless you are working with row vectors, and defining matrix multiplication as $\mathbf{v}A$ (it is more common than you might think).

Comment: Let's see if that is what the OP meant to do

Comment: After I found the matrix I wanted to use it to find the characteristic polynomial , eigenvalues and eigenvectors of f .

Comment: Alright, if you have trouble with that, you can start a new topic ;) @AIP